# Updating a list with ajax and razor

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-ajax

I have a page in asp.net core razor, which is updating the database. I use ajax to go to the controller, the world is done, but I am not able to update the list that the ajax method returns.

This is my `ajax` method:

```
   $.ajax(
        {
            url: "/Uploader/Update",
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                Id: valor
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#LaudosDocumentos").html(data);
            }

        })
```

Here is my `Controller`:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Update(int Id)
        {
            ApplicationUser user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

             Laudos = _context.Laudos.Find(Id);
             Laudos.Excluido = true;
            Laudos.AlteracaoUsuId = user.Id;

            _context.Attach(Laudos).State = EntityState.Modified;
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            Id = Laudos.PessoaId;
            LaudosDocumentos = await _context.Laudos.Where(m => m.PessoaId == Id && m.Excluido == false).ToListAsync();
            return Json( new { LaudosDocumentos });
        }
```

This is my page `cshtml`:

```
<div class="col-sm">
    @if (Model.LaudosDocumentos.Count > 0)
    {
       <label class="control-label" style="margin-left:10px">
             Arquivo(s) encontrado(s)
       </label>
    }
    else
    {
       <label class="control-label" style="margin-left:10px">
            Nenhum arquivo foi enviado para analise.
        </label>
    }
    <div class="btn btn-default btn-file">
        @foreach (var item in Model.LaudosDocumentos)
        {
             var ponto = item.Caminho.IndexOf(".");
             var extensao = item.Caminho.Substring(ponto + 1);

             if (extensao == "png" || extensao == "jpg" || extensao == "gif" || extensao == "jpeg")
             {
                  <a class="example-image-link" href="/uploads/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PessoaId)/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Caminho)" data-lightbox="example-set" data-title="">
                     <img src="/uploads/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PessoaId)/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Caminho)" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Laudos" style="width:200px;  height:200px;" />
                  </a>
                  <span style="font-size:23px; margin-left:10px;"> <i class="far fa-trash-alt" onclick="ExcluirArquivo(@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id));"></i></span>
                  <span> <i class="far fa-trash-alt" onclick="ExcluirArquivo(@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id));"></i></span>
              }
        }
       </div>
 </div>
```

I just need to update the list `Model.LaudosDocumentos`
but without having to pass the `Id` of a `div`.

I've tried to pass the `item` value in ajax but it also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

`Json( new { LaudosDocumentos })` will return Json data , you should create your html markup and associated with Json value using Javascript , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58742455/5751404) is code sample .

If you don't want to create html in javscript manually , you can put the whole `<div>` to partial view , and use ajax to call server side function to query/load the partial view with passed model/value , and at last in success function of Ajax directly load the html using `.html(result);` . [Here](http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/65cfe9cd-b98f-48b7-825d-31ae8008a91a.aspx) is coed sample .